# Position() not returning expected position

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I used code I found on [this site](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/) to create the following bit of code for smooth scrolling within a table:

```
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

       var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
       event.preventDefault();
       var startPoint = $('#schedule-table tbody').position().top;
       $('#schedule-table tbody').animate({
         scrollTop: (target.position().top - startPoint)
       }, 2000);
     });
```

The scroll is working fine. However, position() doesn't always return the correct position to scroll the document correctly.

For example, if you go to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywickham/4rm39m79/1/) and do the following:

1. Click on "Thu 02/11". *It scrolls to the correct position.*
2. Click on "Fri 02/12". *It doesn't scroll to correct position.*

Here is another example after you run the script again:

1. Click on "Fri 02/12". *It scrolls to the correct position.*
2. Click on "Thu 02/11". *It scrolls all the way to the top - past the correct position.*

**My question:**
Can someone explain why I am not getting exact positioning and how to correct the issue? I've read the docs on [scrolltop](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/), [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/), and [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), but there is clearly something I'm not understanding or missing.

Here is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div id="schedule-container">
<div class="schedule-navigation">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#date-2016-02-10">
            <span class="week-day">Wed</span>
            <span class="date">02/10</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
      <a href="#date-2016-02-11">
            <span class="week-day">Thu</span>
            <span class="date">02/11</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#date-2016-02-12">
            <span class="week-day">Fri</span>
            <span class="date">02/12</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<table id="schedule-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="date-2016-02-10">
        <td>2016-02-10
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr id="date-2016-02-11">
        <td>2016-02-11
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr id="date-2016-02-12">
        <td>2016-02-12
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#schedule-container { position: relative; }
table { border: 1px solid black; }
tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
tr:nth-child(even) { background: #CCC; }
td { width: 200px; }
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you include jQuery, it works fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/4rm39m79/2/

Comment: You forgot to include JQuery library.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I did forget to include the library and have updated my question and corrected the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by playing with the code a little more.

What I didn't understand was the position of my elements were changing with each click. I had made the assumption the initial position remained the same since there was no page reload happening.

However, with each click, the position of the elements was changing in relation to the parent element with positioning.

Therefore, I either needed to capture the original positions and look those up on each click, or capture the new position and animate scrolltop based on the current position and the location of the new position. I'm not sure that I'm explaining that all too well, so...

Here is the code that makes the table scroll to the correct position:

```
currentPosition = 0;

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

  var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
  event.preventDefault();

  var currentScrollTop = $('#schedule-table tbody').scrollTop();

  currentPosition = target.position().top;
  $('#schedule-table tbody').animate({
    scrollTop: (currentPosition + currentScrollTop)
  }, 1000);

});
```

Here is the [new jsfiddle with the working code](https://jsfiddle.net/ywickham/zvejsc31/1/).